# developer tags in youtube php api

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

Has anyone got the developer tags working with the php zend client library?

I have uploaded videos with developer tag of "BABYLON__"

Following the [api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos) instructions it should be able to retrieve only those videos with developer tags attached using the code below

```
$devTagUrl =
'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com' .
'%2Fschemas%2F2007%2Fdevelopertags.cat%7DBABYLON__';

// obtain a feed with videos matching the provided developer tag
$yt->getVideoFeed($devTagUrl);
```

however this returns nothing. I know the videos exist, as a call to

```
$devTagUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";
$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($devTagUrl);
```

pulls all videos into the feed.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a delay between uploading and developer tags being available for searching on. do not expect your videos to be searchable immediately you have uploaded them, delay can be over an hour!